# Tag and Metadata searching doesn't work in Spotlight

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search, metadata

There's a problem with searching for a tags and metadata e.g. kind:movie in my Spotlight. Actually, it doesn't work even tag:Red in Spotlight. It's weird, because I can search easy using Finder, but not using Spotlight. It might be problem with indexing. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reindexing:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

This will reindex the entire drive and all connected volumes.